# Artinian ring and injective endomorphism which is not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have tried to find a left module $M$ over an artinian ring $R$ with an injective endomorphism that is not an automorphism, so is there any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R=F$ to be a field, and consider $M=\prod_{i\in \mathbb N}F$.

You can inject $M$ onto the subspace of $M$ whose even coordinates are $0$, but this map is not surjective.

Comment: but i need map between V to itself not to subspace of V !

Comment: @MaramOs You understand that a subspace of $M$ is a subset of $M$, right?

Comment: @rschwieb yes, they are subsets and vector spaces of V

Comment: @MaramOs So a map from $M$ to a subspace of $M$ is an endomorphism of $M$.

Comment: "In abstract algebra, the endomorphism ring of an abelian group $X$, denoted by $End(X)$, is the set of all homomorphisms of $X$ into itself"

Comment: @MaramOs Do you see why my answer works then ? I'm not sure why you're quoting that to me .

Comment: actually I couldn't see what you mean but my solution is $R$=$A1$ and $M$=$Z$[$x$] with $f$:$Z$[$x$] onto $Z$[$x$] by $f$($g$)=$2g$ where $A1$ is Weyl Algebra.

Comment: @MaramOs well, the Weyl algebra is not artinian, so that does not seem useful. You also didn't explain the $R$ module action on $Z[x]$. Really my example is about as simple as you can get

Comment: can I say ? $M$=$R$[$X$] and $R$ is real number and $f$($g$)=$g$/$(x-1)$.

Comment: @MaramOs No. $(x-1)$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb R [x]$, so no. Besides, even if it was invertible, ther is obviously an inverse map, so it is a bijection.

Comment: @MaramOs But, if you take $R=\mathbb R$ and $M=\mathbb R[x]$, and the map $f(x)\mapsto f(x^2)$, that would work ( in fact, it is one way to write my solution)

Comment: but i do not need the inverse because i talk about module. it is enough to be group abelian and close under multiplication and satisfied the properties of multiple by scalars. I'm right @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs I don't know what you mean by "$g/(x-1)$" then if you're not talking about multiplying $g$ by $(x-1)^{-1}$.

Comment: I mean $g$ divided by $(x-1)$ anyway it is not right also your answer because they are not homomorphism @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs Both *are* $\mathbb R$ homomorphisms

Comment: by $x$ goes to $x2$ How?

Comment: @MaramOs  what axiom of homomorphisms do you think fails?

Comment: the addition of two element then the image it is  not equal the the sum of two images. @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs But it *is* equal. If you add two polynomials and then replace $x$ with $x^2$, you get the same thing as if you had first replaced the $x$ with $x^2$ and then added.

Comment: @MaramOs Even if you don't want to agree to that example, it is still very easy to see the original thing I described. Just map the $i$th coordinate to the $2i+1$ coordinate for every $i$.

Comment: ok, I thought you mean whole the function $h$$(g+f)$=$(g+f)^2$. i took $f$ from $Z[x]$ onto itself by defined $f$ as $x$ goes to $2x$ and the artinian ring is $Z$ mod $5$. I hope it is right. @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs That is indeed an injective $\mathbb Z[x]$ map that isn't surjective, but $\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a $\mathbb Z_5$ module. So no, that is not correct.

Comment: why Z is not Z mod 5 module?

Comment: I am sorry i mean $Z$ not $Z[x]$ and x i mean a number and the image just multiple by 2 @rschwieb

Comment: Because $5x\neq 0$ in )\mathbb Z[x]$, but $5=0$ in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Unfortunately yes I took zero in this question @rschwieb

Comment: Can i ask you another question about ideals? @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs If it's brief enough for a comment, OK.

Comment: thank you, I have tried to prove the socle of $R$ is a two sided ideal. where the socle is all the simple left ideal of $R$. 1) can I assume the sum of ideals is finite? 2) if I prove there is an isomorphic between $I$ and $Ix$, $x$ in $R$ how this can help me with socle. Thanks @rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs 1) No, the sum can be infinite in general. 2) It proves that $Ix$ is another simple left ideal, and it should be contained in the (left) socle.

Comment: ok, so how can i prove the socle is a two-sided ideal and is it a normal sum or direct,please? thank so much...@rschwieb

Comment: @MaramOs What we just talked about trivially proves that $(\sum S_i)x\subseteq \sum S_i$, where I have indexed the simple left ideals as $S_i$.  If you are asking if the sum is a sum or a direct sum, then you haven't even understood the problem clearly. The left socle is typically defined to be the sum of *all* simple left submodules. This is obviously not always a direct sum (just look at $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ as an $\mathbb R$ module.) However, every socle *can* be expressed as a direct sum of some of the submodules inside it.

Comment: you are right i could not understand and that why i cannot do it or write down anything. but I really want to know because i cannot write down anything if I do not understand it. anyway thank you, @rschwieb